# Flow doesn't report the styled components coverage

Tags: flowtype, styled-components, flow-typed

I think I might be missing something in the flow configuration. I am trying to check the flow coverage and flow reports the styled components are not covered. I am using [flow-coverage-report](https://github.com/rpl/flow-coverage-report) to check the flow coverage.

I have installed styled components in flow-typed and is under `flow-typed/npm`

#### Versions

- flow version: 0.92.1
- styled-components: 4.1.3
- flow-coverage-report: 0.6.1
- flow-typed: 2.5.1

[image: Flow Coverage for styled components]

My Flow Config

```
[ignore]
**Test.js
./node_modules/*

[include]
./src/*

[libs]
./flow-typed
```

Can anyone please help to figure out the problem why styled-components are missing from flow coverage.